# DataFrame to MongoDB

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, dataframe, pymongo

I have a high-nested dictionary with pandas dataframes like:

```
{HEAD: 
    {NameOne: 
        {TAG : VALUE}
    }
    {NameTwo : DataFrame}
    {NameThree : DataFrame}
}
```

and I want to send it to MongoDB via PyMongo

```
client = MongoClient('mylink')
db = client['DB_NAME']
collection = db['COLLECTION_NAME']
file = {...}
collection.insert_one(file)
```

But I have this error:

> bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: ***he show my
>   Dataframe here*** of type:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pymongo needs to be able to convert each element of the dictionary into something it can store as a BSON document. If you try and insert somehting it can't convert (such as a pandas dataframe), you will see the `InvalidDocument` exception.

You will have to convert each of the embedded dataframes to something pymongo can encode before you can store the document in MongoDB.

You could start with [`df.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).